# Using Typescript's baseUrl compiler option with node

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0, compiler-options

### Can `node`'s module loader support TS's `baseUrl` compiler option?

TS 2 introduced the `baseUrl` compiler option, to effectively enable project relative `require()` and `import` requests.

However, this requires the module loader to support the same thing, as TS doesn't actually rewrite the request during transpilation. For tools like webpack, this is fairly straightforward.

Unfortunately, when using TS to develop `node` applications (.i.e backend services, command line tools, electron desktop apps) there didn't seem to be a way to change node's module loader behavior.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes!

Appreciating TS's position, here's a simple solution to the 90% use case for those of us using `node`, but wanting the convenience of using `baseUrl` relative `require()` calls without any fuss.

This solution hooks `node`'s `require()` call, and resolves requests using the `dirname` of "main" to mimic `baseUrl`. It therefore assumes the `baseUrl` compiler option was also set to the same directory where the source "main.ts" was located.

To use, paste this tiny chunk of code at the top of your "main.ts".

```
import * as path from 'path'
import * as fs from 'fs'
(function() {
  const CH_PERIOD = 46
  const baseUrl = path.dirname(process['mainModule'].filename)
  const existsCache = {d:0}; delete existsCache.d
  const moduleProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(module)
  const origRequire = moduleProto.require
  moduleProto.require = function(request) {
    let existsPath = existsCache[request]
    if(existsPath === undefined) {
      existsPath = ''
      if(!path.isAbsolute(request) && request.charCodeAt(0) !== CH_PERIOD) {
        const ext = path.extname(request)
        const basedRequest = path.join(baseUrl, ext ? request : request + '.js')
        if(fs.existsSync(basedRequest)) existsPath = basedRequest
        else {
          const basedIndexRequest = path.join(baseUrl, request, 'index.js')
          existsPath = fs.existsSync(basedIndexRequest) ? basedIndexRequest : ''
        }
      }
      existsCache[request] = existsPath
    }
    return origRequire.call(this, existsPath || request)
  }
})()
```